# Where are the OpenVPN connection logs and configuration files?

Tags: log, openvpn

I have problem connecting to OpenVPN server. Where are OpenVPN log files and how do I find the connection details?

Comment: in general, you can found configuration files on `/etc/openvpn/` there was contained log files and your openVPN configuration

Comment: Here's the [documentation page](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/troubleshooting-client-vpn-tunnel-connectivity/) you need

Comment: Are you interested in troubleshooting the client, or the server? I think it's useful to ask for both, but it's just nice to know. (I know this is an old question)

Answer (score 118, accepted):

If you are using the network manager plugin (**network-manager-openvpn**), look into **/var/log/syslog**

This should give you the last logs of openvpn:

```
$ grep VPN /var/log/syslog
```

Connection details are to be found in **/etc/openvpn/**

Comment: Could also be called `openvpnas.log` in `/var/log/`

Comment: This was good in 2014 and searches might lead to here. In 2021, many distros switched to systemd and the logs are accessible via journalctl, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/885383/where-are-network-manager-logs-16-04.

Comment: `grep vpn -i /var/log/syslog` is better to use.

grep is case-sensitive by default and in my case it was missing an important warning : `Jan 11 22:12:06 blablabla-nix nm-openvpn[3890]: WARNING: Your certificate has expired!`

Comment: even better, use `less` to browse easily in your terminal: 
`grep -i VPN /var/log/syslog | less +G`

Answer (score 54):

By default, in most distros, OpenVPN log output goes to the syslog, which is usually at `/var/log/syslog`

However, your config files can set the logfile location explicitly, e.g.:

```
log-append /var/log/openvpn.log
```

This works for both OpenVPN clients and servers. OpenVPN config files are usually located in `/etc/openvpn` and usually named `*.conf`. `server.conf` is canonical; client config filenames are usually like `<client name/>.conf`.

Answer (score 31):

### Log file location

On servers, OpenVPN is usually run as a system service, i.e., started with the
`--daemon` option. According to the OpenVPN man page, using the `--daemon [progname]`
option has the following effect:

> Become  a daemon after all initialization functions are completed.  This
>   option will cause all message and error output to be sent to the syslog file
>   (such as `/var/log/messages`), except for the output of scripts and ifconfig
>   commands, which will go to `/dev/null` unless otherwise redirected.  The
>   syslog redirection occurs immediately at the point that `--daemon` is parsed
>   on the command line even though the daemonization point occurs later.  If
>   one  of  the `--log` options is present, it will supercede (sic) syslog
>   redirection.

Use either of the `--log file` or `--log-append file` options if you want OpenVPN
messages to be logged to a different file. The `--log` option causes the
specified log file to be over-written each time the OpenVPN daemon starts
while the `--log-append` option adds new entries to the log file. These
options can also be set in the OpenVPN configuration file, e.g.,

```
log /var/log/openvpn.log
```

### Verbosity

The `--verb` option can be used to set the log file verbosity from 0 (no
output except for fatal errors) to 11 (for maximum debugging information).
The man page specifies levels of 1 to 4 as the appropriate range for normal
usage. This behaviour can be set in the OpenVPN configuration file, e.g.,

```
verb 3
```

Comment: I changed to `verb 2` from the default 3, but there was no noticeable difference. I then `rm openvpn.log` thinking of restarting a fresh log. But openvpn.log didn't get created and I now can't find the logs. Where has the log gone to now? I created a new openvpn.log but it remained at size 0.

Comment: @OldGeezer That would best be asked as a new question where you can provide specific details about the configuration of your OpenVPN and OS logging (systemd/syslog) configuration.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `-l` or `--syslog` argument calling openconnect. Now you can check with `tail -f /var/log/syslog`

Answer (score 2):

For people from 2023 who googled this, here is how you can view OpenVPN logs in modern Ubuntu with systemd via journalctl:

```
sudo journalctl -u openvpn-server@server.service
```

Then by pressing `Shift` + `G` you can scroll down to the most recent lines.

You can also activate follow mode by specifying `-f` to automatically scroll down as new entries come:

```
sudo journalctl -u openvpn-server@server.service -f
```

Comment: I can confirm from 2024. Also `-e` makes it more comfortable

Answer (score 1):

It is supposed to be in your home directory (home directory of the user whom executing it), eg `~`. Running an `ls -l` command will perhaps reveal it. On the other hand, you may start openvpn with `--debug` option to capture what's happening realtime on the terminal.