# How can I obtain the IP address of OpenVPN clients

Tags: scripts, openvpn, client

The OpenVPN server gives an internal IP addresses to each client that is connecting outside of the network. I want to store these IP addresses in a database after they are assigned. Is there an easy way to tell which IP addresses were handed out by the OpenVPN Server?

thanks for Help

Comment: Have you looked at the logs of the OpenVPN server?  It should just be a simple matter of `grep`ing for a successful log in line and piping that to your database utility.

Comment: You can predefine an IP address for each client using entries in the ccd directory.

Comment: the address are dynamically assigned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these aren't statically assigned there isn't a good way to do this other than to extract them from the logfiles since the connections will be randomly assigned IP addresses.

If they are statically assigned AND you are using the Open VPN AccessServer you can do it this way:

```
sudo /usr/local/openvpn_as/scripts/sacli UserPropGet
```

which should yield a list of the IP addresses in the output which should look something like this:

```
{
  "<< name_of_user_profile >>": {
    ...
    "conn_ip": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

where the `conn_ip` is the connection IP address.

---

If you are trying to merely log users IP addresses and deposit that info into a DB then you might look at this:

[Where are the OpenVPN connection logs and configuration files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/276664/where-are-the-openvpn-connection-logs-and-configuration-files)

In that case you are using an OpenVPN Access Server you may want to try:

```
grep "primary virtual IP" /var/log/openvpnas.log** > output_file_name
```

which will give you a file with all of the IP addresses associated with all the users.  From there you can further modify the output to get just the bits you want from the file.

Comment: Thanks, yes he address  are dynamically assigned 
i will try that, my goal is to applicate for each user a rule to connect for just  some device, for example ,this user X can connect just to device X.

also i must first know for each user that he have, and store it in Database.

Comment: I've modified the answer to get you more/less exactly what you're looking for in your case--it should work on virtually any OpenVPN server--not just the professional one (with a few modifications, like your log names may be a little different.) If that's good enough you can mark it as 'answered'.

Comment: thanks , i will try it, my senrio is when clients are connected get IP and when they are disconnected get IP of disconnected , also for any change ==> update DB
i want to use Option 
--client connect  /path/script_parsing_connected_IP.sh
-- client disconnecz /path/script_parsing_disconnected_IP.sh

when i try it, i will tell you if work

Comment: hi, i tried what you tell me , its work. i write also a script client-connect and  can know adress IP with variable env. common_name and ip_config_pool ans its work... know i will develop my scipt , to know in runtime (receive notification) when a client connect or disconnect and store in DB

Comment: `cat /var/log/openvpnas.log | grep "primary virtual IP"` worked perfectly for me 

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at /etc/openvpn/openvpn-status.log:

```
OpenVPN CLIENT LIST
Updated,Fri Sep  4 11:07:18 2020
Common Name,Real Address,Bytes Received,Bytes Sent,Connected Since
client1,11.12.13.14:44444,50000,25000,Fri Sep  4 11:00:54 2020
client2,11.12.13.15:44444,27000,5500,Fri Sep  4 11:00:52 2020
ROUTING TABLE
Virtual Address,Common Name,Real Address,Last Ref
10.8.0.7,client1,11.12.13.14:44444,Fri Sep  4 11:06:13 2020
10.8.0.6,client2,client2,11.12.13.15:44444,Fri Sep  4 11:03:56 2020
GLOBAL STATS
Max bcast/mcast queue length,2
END
```

Comment: I used openvpn-hook "--client-connect" and "--learn-address". Via comon name, virtual address , when the user connect openvp the script return these values