# How to configure openvpn log location and verbosity when using network-manager-openvpn on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, network-manager, openvpn

[A previous question mentions](https://askubuntu.com/a/588920/43311) that the log can be directed to a file instead of syslog and the log verbosity can be increased. I'm trying to debug an issue with my vpn and am not sure where I'd add these configuration settings for use with network-manager-openvpn gui.